# how to build Android M source code for nexus 9

Tags: android

I already downloaded Android source code and vendor image from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/blobs-preview.
Build the source code on Ubuntu14.04 and it is successful. I try to flash the image to Nexus 9. When it reboot, the screen is stopped on "android".
Command to flash is below:

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash cache cache.img 
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash vendor vendor.img
fastboot reboot
```

Who else meet this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: The above `fastboot` code flashes it to the device. Is the issue with the flashing or the building?

Comment: which product did you use for building ?

Comment: @Huey, after flashing the image which is built by me, the device is reboot and it is stop on "android" screen.

Comment: @RahulPatil, I download the master branch of source code and built it.

Answer (score 0):

As device/htc/flounder device is not configured to build, vendor.img you built is not complete, only a default one. Download the vendor partition on a Nexus 9 factory image from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images instead of the vendor.img you build by AOSP.

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite

Comment: @AnirudhSharma Link isn't to an answering document, but to the required source the OP may need.  Nothing really quotable there.  Explanation could be more detailed, but seems to suffice.